# How to use RequestContext in primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm new to primefaces. I trying some examples in [primeface showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/callbackParams.jsf)

**But;**

After `saveUser`, on ajax method `handleComplete(xhr, status, args)` args don't have arguments that added in `saveUser` method.

**EDIT** : I just added `@ManagedBean` annotations because i'm using jsf 2.0

**EDIT-2**

in my pom;

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

in my web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

in my .xhtml page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

<h:head>

    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {  
            if(args.validationFailed) {  
                alert("Validation Failed");  
            } else {  
                alert("Save:" + args.saved);  
                alert("FirstName: " + args.user.firstname + ", Lastname: " + args.user.lastname);   
            }  
        }  
    </script> 

</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="panel" header="New User">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *" />
            <p:inputText id="firstname" value="#{user.firstName}" required="true"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Lastname: *"  />
            <p:inputText id="surname" value="#{user.surName}" required="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{user.saveUser}" oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)" />
</h:form>


</h:body>
</html>
```

in my bean;

```
@ManagedBean(name = "user")
public class User {

    private String firstName = "";
    private String surName = "";

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }

    public void saveUser(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // save user
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addCallbackParam("saved", true);
        context.addCallbackParam("user", this);
    }

}
```

**EDIT -3**

I can catch properties that carried with data in ajax response with `this.PrimeFaces.ajax.RequestManager.requests[0].data` it carries that data ;

```
"j_id2059540600_7ac21836=j_id2059540600_7ac21836&j_id2059540600_7ac21836%3Afirstname=qweq&j_id2059540600_7ac21836%3Asurname=asda&javax.faces.ViewState=8900392402396831372%3A-8139730777939772917&javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=j_id2059540600_7ac21836:j_id2059540600_7ac218a5&javax.faces.partial.execute=@all&j_id2059540600_7ac21836:j_id2059540600_7ac218a5=j_id2059540600_7ac21836:j_id2059540600_7ac218a5"
```

But i'm pretty sure there is another option. Just can't seet it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you edit your question to include to following code: (a) the `<p:ajax>` element and its parent element from your Facelets page, and (b) your action listener method from your managed bean.

Comment: i can post them here but nothing more than in my ref.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly with calling handleComplete?  What `args` are you expecting to be automatically passed as an argument?  Remember JSF has its own built in validation and the action `#{user.saveUser}` will not be called if validation fails on the server side.  I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: thanks for response. I'm just playing with components for now. I expect to see from client side that desired/created beans properties, not expect to see if there is a validation about the action that or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was about scope problem of a form that contains a commandButton. Command buttons (i think..didnt read a formal document about it.) that in a form has a scope of its own form. Cant reach/update/modify elements in an form.

Comment: You can, but you need to write the id in this format: `formid:elementid`. The Javadoc for the `findComponent()` method makes it clearer than I can regarding the syntax for element ids: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#findComponent(java.lang.String)